# Query to select cards and transactions

Tags: sql-server, query, relational-division

I have some trouble with a query definition. My database is about operations in a bank and I want to show the card numbers which were used in transactions at all ATMs.

This is how my tables DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Cards(
    card_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    number VARCHAR(25),
    CVV CHAR(3),
    bankAccount_id INT REFERENCES BankAccount(account_id)
);
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
    transaction_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ATM_id INT REFERENCES ATM(id),
    card_number INT REFERENCES Cards(card_id),
    sum_money INT,
    transaction_time DATETIME
);
```

And I tried below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cards C
WHERE C.card_id = ALL (SELECT *
                        FROM Transactions T
                        WHERE T.card_number = C.card_id
                        )
```

And it doesn't work since I used card_id on both sides. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: For your information, this is a relational division problem, and I've added a corresponding tag to your question. The [tag's info page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/relational-division/info) contains more details as well as some links, if you are curious to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT T.card_number
FROM Cards AS C 
INNER JOIN Transactions AS T
    ON C.card_id = T.card_number
GROUP BY T.card_number -- Grouping up on Card_Number to get the count of unique ATMs each card was used at in the HAVING clause
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ATM_id) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ATM) -- Count of distinct ATMs each card was used at needs to equal the total number of ATMs
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense, but it's not that easy to think this way

Comment: @andrei1234589 No problem! It takes time and practice but eventually it becomes intuitive. Reading up on `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses would help in this particular case. (Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if its helpful, so its shown as complete and verifiable for others to use.)